# DOMDocument->load external entity fail for local file with PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, libxml2, php

The following PHP "failed to load external entity", even though it is trying to load a local XML file:

```
<?php
  $path = "/usr/share/pear/www/horde/config";
  #libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $v = $dom->load($path . '/conf.xml');
  echo "status = ".($v?'success':'error')."\n";
?>
```

The basic question is how can this be fixed?

Log file:

```
2014/03/10 20:07:10 [error] 26117#0: *24 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/pear/www/horde/config/conf.xml" in /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php on line 5
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. DOMDocument->load() /usr/share/nginx/html/test.php:5" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com"
```

Uncommenting the `libxml_disable_entity_loader` line works, but this is not an acceptable solution for a few reasons, e.g. it is systemwide for php-fpm.

Running the PHP from shell returns "status = success".  Doing a `file_get_contents` and then `$dom->loadXML($string)` also works (i.e. file exists and not a permissions issue).  This might be an acceptable workaround, but shouldn't be necessary and doesn't explain why the error is occurring.

The XML file itself is the [Horde config](https://github.com/horde/horde/blob/master/horde/config/conf.xml), but the problem does not seem to be the contents of the file, since it also occurs with this XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration></configuration>
```

Environment is php and php-fpm 5.3.3, nginx 1.4.6, libxml2 2.7.6.  My first guess is something to do with php-fpm, but I can't find any config setting that affects this.  Any pearls of wisdom appreciated!

**EDIT TO ADD**

Restarting php-fpm causes it to work briefly.  Disabling APC did not seem to help.  Seems like something with php-fpm - but what?

**FURTHER TESTING**

Some additional info:

1. I tried hitting the server repeatedly, and get an error about 80% of the time.  The pattern isn't random - a few seconds of successes followed by a series of errors;
2. I added a `phpinfo()` to the end of the above php and doing a `diff` on the success and failure runs - there is no difference;
3. If I put `libxml_disable_entity_loader(true)`, I seem to *always* get an error, which suggests that [bug #64938](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64938) is at work.

It seems that I need to find *why* the XML is considered to have external entities.

Comment: Check your permissions on the file in question.

Comment: @ElefantPhace permissions OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that, if the external entity loader is disabled, it should be obvious that [external entities can't be loaded](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4b7148711b7200999c96ee4d43c5206c08e6765b/ext/libxml/libxml.c#L381). The only solution is to enable loading of external entities with `libxml_disable_entity_loader(false)`. Since this setting is not thread-safe, I can see two approaches:

- Enable it globally and use some other feature to prevent loading of unwanted entities (typically from a network):

  - Register your own entity loader with `libxml_set_external_entity_loader`. I think that's the safest solution.
  - Use the parse option `LIBXML_NONET`. This should be enough if you simply want to disable network access of libxml2. But you have to make sure to always pass it to calls like `DOMDocument::load`.
- Use locks to protect calls to `libxml_disable_entity_loader`. This is probably impractical and potentially unsafe.

Comment: Remember I'm testing with `<?xml version="1.0"?><configuration></configuration>`.  That XML doesn't have any external entities that I can see - but please correct me!  So perhaps an intermediate question is 'why would `libxml_disable_entity_loader(true)` (notice the `true`) give an external entity error when loading that basic XML?

Comment: "External entity loader" is a bit of a misnomer in libxml2. It is used to load all kinds of external resources. Maybe it is even used to load the main XML file itself.

Comment: I think this statement is correct.  It seems that even a local file is considered a 'URI' and (by libxml2 definition) an 'external entity', even if it does not contain `<!ENTITY`.